# Can "substantial" mean "suprisingly small in amount"?

Tags: word-meaning

From a TOEFL reading passage

> Paragraph 5：Ryan and his colleagues measured the rates of predation in
> Tungara Frog choruses of different sizes. Large choruses of Frogs did
> not attract more bats than small choruses, and consequently the risk
> of predation for an individual Frog was less in a large chorus than in
> a small one. Predation was an astonishing 19 percent of the Frogs per
> night in the smallest chorus and a ***substantial*** 1.5 percent per
> night even in the largest chorus. Predation, therefore, is a risk in choruses of all sizes, but the risk varies depending on the type of call used. When a male Frog shifts from a
> simple whine to a whine-chuck call, it increases its chances of
> attracting a female, but it simultaneously increases its risk of
> attracting a predator. In small choruses, the competition from other
> males for females is relatively small, and the risk of predation is
> relatively large. Under these conditions it is apparently advantageous
> for a male Tungara Frog to give simple whines. However, as chorus size
> increases, competition with other males also increases while the risk
> of predation falls. In that situation, the advantage of giving a
> complex call apparently outweighs the risks.
>
> Question 9: The word ***substantial*** in the passage is closest in meaning
> to
>
> O average
>
> O smaller
>
> O ***considerable***
>
> O surprising

I think compared with 19 percent, 1.5 percent cent is a suprisingly small amount. However, I think substantial and considerable only mean large in amount or degree. Therefore, I find the use of substantial in the passage weird. While considerable is a synonym, it is equally weird to use in the passage.

Comment: 19.5 per cent was 'astonishing' which rules out 'surprising' as the answer, and the dictionary meaning of 'substantial' should give you some guidance.

Comment: Though the number may seem small to you, only the opinion of the writer is important here. The rest of that sentence and the one following it make it clear that even a 1.5% rate is "considerable" according to the writer.

Comment: @gotube thanks for highlighting the hint that I ignored and for the deduction work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would say it is the "considerable" meaning that is intended. That for a frog to have a 1.5% chance each night of being caught by a predator that it is a significant risk for those frogs (of course, nothing like the 19% chance for frogs in smaller populations).

The proper comparison to keep in mind is 0% if there weren't predators. And in that framing I would agree with the author that 1.5% chance per night is a substantial risk.

Comment: If I were a frog invited to join a chorus with 199 others, and was told that three of us were likely to be eaten by bats, I am pretty sure I would decide to stay home that night.

Answer (score 2):

That sentence doesn't mean that 1.5 percent was a "surprisingly small amount" to the authors. It means that while 19 percent is astonishing, even 1.5 percent is higher than they expected.

So, "considerable" is the right answer here, in that it's closest to the meaning of the statement. The authors are saying that number is large.